# DDMS won't delete file on SDCard

Tags: android, file, android-sdcard, delete-file, ddms

I am using DDMS to attempt to delete a file on the emulator SD card.  It won't delete.  I can delete other files, I can export the file and move files onto the SD card, but this particular file will not delete.

[image]

I have even tried to delete it with

```
adb shell rm /mnt/sdcard/myfolder/myfile.ext
```

Please advise

Comment: If you want to remove something with the adb shell, you must either first cd to its directory, or more commonly specify an `absolute path`   - an example might be adb shell rm /mnt/sdcard/your/file/path/name **but the actual mount point and thus absolute path of the sdcard is device/version dependent**

Answer (score 1):

@Android Addict - you can also use the Option:

Eclipse->Windows->show view->other->File Explorer

From File Explorer you can find the respective file can delete it from SDCARD, Even can add files from the PC.

Hope this will solve your problem..

Comment: @ApproorvaFaldu  My apologies, I should have been more clear.  I am trying to delete it with DDMS file explorer.

Comment: @AndroidAddict - Oh Okay, One other tedious way could be that you ll find the sdcard.img file in the tmp/.android/avd/<emulatore-name>/sdcard.img  , you can play around opening this img file with any software.. i know its vague but can be a solution.